# Android reference Paint Class reset

Tags: java, android

I am wondering how the reset method of the paint class is implemented

Paint Class reference .

```
public void reset() {
    throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
}

public void set(Paint src) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
}
```

Where is it implemented?

And is there a way to easily find it?

Comment: Yes, there is an easy way to find it, google "android paint source": http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.robolectric/android-all/4.3_r2-robolectric-0/android/graphics/Paint.java#Paint.reset%28%29

Comment: oh Very Good ..

Comment: Is there a way to easily find the method implementation in the Android studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to see the implementation from Android Studio you need to download the source code for the Sdk you're compiling with.

with Android Studio 2.3:
. open the Sdk Manager
. click on "Show Package Details" in the "Sdk Platform Tab".
. find the Sdk level you're compiling with (e.g. api 25 -> Android 7.1.1)
. check "Source for Android 25"
. click on apply and ok
. you should see the download starting
. maybe you need to restart Android Studio, maybe not